# cannot open .scproj project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sitecore

I am trying to open my solution in **Visual Studio 2010**.  I have 8 projects and four of them will not open due to the following error.

```
".scproj cannot be opened because its project type (.scproj) is not
supported by this version of the application"
```

Is this a setting in Visual studio or some configuration?  **Note:** this is a Sitecore 6.4 Website if that changes anything.

Comment: `.SCproj` is a Sitecore Project File.

Comment: @Paul The answer to the question posed in your title is 'Yes', or possibly 'No'. Please change your title something meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

Scproj files are used by TDS -Team Development for Sitecore

https://www.hhogdev.com/Downloads/Team-Development-for-Sitecore.aspx

If it is a TDS project file then you'll need to install TDS to load the project files.

Comment: Thank you, I am certain this is what the issue. I am new to this company, so I know what to do now.